# How can I model this database in order to handle this query

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization

There is a source who provides data in the following format, and I have to designed tables based on this format. Should I keep their existing structure or break them up into several tables?

The first table:

```
ItemId     PropertyId      Value

A1           10            Black
A1           20            16gb
A1           30            Iphone6
A1           1000          Apple
```

The property reference table:

```
PropetyID     Value

10            Color
20            Memory Size
30            Item Name
100           Product Group
```

There can be more than 2000 distinct properties. The table designed at the end should be capable of answering the following question:

```
How many white iPhones of 16gb were sold?
```

Comment: This looks like a homework question.   The StackOverflow community should not be doing your homework.

Comment: generally, mark this as homework, or provide some attempt that you have made.

Comment: The EAV model can be a pain to use, but it has its place. I think the basic rule is to separate data out according to data type, so dates are held in a date data type, integers in an INT, etc. This can be done by separating data into separate tables according to data type.

Answer (score 0):

This design looks good to me, as it doesn't break any noticeable normalization rules. In addition, this is designed in a way to write the query you are looking for.

Because I suspect this is a homework question, I am not going to write your entire query for you, but I will give you a rough guideline, and you will have to convert it to SQL. To find white 16 gb iPhones:

- Select itemIDs where value 10 is equal to white, value 20 is equal to 16gb and value 30 is equal to iPhone.
- Since these conditions cannot hold true on each row, you need to query for rows matching one of those conditions (hint: `OR` operator).
- That being said, you will then need to find out which itemIDs matched all three of those conditions (hint: `HAVING` clause).

A rough skeleton:

```
SELECT items
FROM myTable
WHERE itemIsWhite OR itemIs16gp OR itemIsIphone
GROUP BY item
HAVING threeRowsReturned
```

If you get stuck on anything feel free to ask, but I highly recommend you try this on your own, as I have given you a lot to start with.

Comment: This is an Amazon interview question related to data modelling...i was curious to know the answer to this question....the answer is snowflaking The table....i just need to know how we do that since i havent spent time as a data modeller

Comment: @HussainAliMirza it's hard to tell 100%, but it looks good to me if those are all the columns. It might be easier if you made one row for each product having columns `product, color, size, name, group` in one table.

Comment: Really, it all depends on context I guess.

Comment: I actually told them if we can dedicate one column for one property...However then they said they have 2000 properties....Have a property in a seperate row would make it hard to answer a Query Like " How many black 16gb Wifi Apple Ipad-Minis Have i sold"....Where you would end up having 5 properties for 1 Product